# Can fission and fusion happen together?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Like making up them together first splitting in the term of fission then adding them up.

Answer (score 1):

Some nuclei release energy when fusing and some nuclei release energy when splitting. One nucleus $^{56}$Fe is the most stable of all, and requires energy both to fission and to fuse. The keyword here is *nuclear binding energy*.

You can certainly split light nuclei or fuse heavier one, but this requires huge amount of energy which is typically found in star explosions or in particle accelerators.

[image]

Comment: … but can both happen *together*?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - do you consider the compound nucleus in a reaction a fusion event, followed by it splitting back up as a fission event?

Comment: @JonCuster point well made but you should ask the OP that question…

Comment: It is not true that Iron always requires energy to fuse. If that were true, there would be no stable elements heavier than Iron.

Comment: @tobalt It only means that elements heavier than iron cannot be produced by "burning" lighter elements as normally happens in stars. But the universe has other strategies to produce heavier elements: to learn more look up for "nucleosynthesis of heavy nuclei" (s process, r process, p process, ...)

Answer (score 1):

> Like making up them together first splitting in the term of fission
> then adding them up.

Sort of, yes, this is the basis for the fission-fusion hybrid reactor.

Fission is triggered by neutrons. Some elements are really happy to fission even with low-energy neutrons, but most require some minimum energy. The problem with fission is that one fission event might release neutrons that are too low-energy to start another. A good example is U238, which is available in huge amounts, but the neutrons it give off won't cause a chain reaction. U235, on the other hand, can cause a chain reaction, so that's what we use in a reactor.

Fusion is *not* driven by neutrons, bur heat. So the key design in a fusion reactor is to keep the heat in the reactor as long as possible - this is called the "confinement time". Neutrons are actually a problem in fusion, because they cannot be captured in the fuel (which is a thin gas) and they carry energy out of the reactor and cool it off. And this is why we've had so much trouble building fusion reactors, we simply can't make one that keeps the heat in long enough.

So one idea is this, take a fusion reactor and wrap it in U238. The fusion neutrons are way more energetic than needed, so the U238 undergoes fission - even after a fission that neutron has enough energy to cause another atom to do the same, on average you get 2 or 3 fissions per fusion. All of those fissions release energy. So now the total energy released by each fusion is "multiplied" by the number of fissions it causes upstream. So even with a "subcritical" fusion reactor, like the ones we can already build, you might get out more energy than you put in.

But...

The problem with D-T fusion is that while we can get D easily enough, T does not exist in nature in large amounts. So the idea from the start was to "breed" more T using the neutrons from the fusion. And it's just *barely* possible, if you lose too many neutrons out of the reactor or absorbed in the reactor walls and such you'll have too little T to run the reactor. So... how can you use them to make fission if losing any means you can't run the fusion reactor?

And that's why we don't have fission-fusion hybrids.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that in a hydrogen bomb, a fission reaction is used to generate the temperature and pressure needed to ignite fusion.

Answer (score 0):

In general sense - NO. Very heavy atoms (like U, Pu) releases binding energy while decaying into a bit lighter ones. Very light atoms (like H, He) releases binding energy upon merging into a bit heavier atoms. H fission will not produce *heavy enough* atoms for effective $\Delta E = \Delta m c^2$ mass transfer, and U fusion, will not produce *light enough* atoms for effective join procedure with high energy output. So these two types of energy output does not overlap very much, unless U fusion, can act as a temperature source (catalysator) for starting a H fission reaction (as in H bombs). But it would be just like a match for starting a camp fire,- after that - no use of it.

Even if there could exist such element (or elements pair) which could support fusion and fission reactions at once,- chain reaction would hardly start at all, because you could get energy output loop $\to$ fusion-fission-fusion with no additional energy input. I.E. this would break first law of thermodynamics, which says that no system can make work without *constant* energy input.

Answer (score 0):

A [lithium deuteride thermonuclear bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Bravo) works by a fission-fusion cycle. Deuterium-tritium fusion yields neutrons which fission lithium to helium and tritium, thus making more tritium to continue the cycle.